# Transform Data in R

Tags: r

I have uploaded a data set into R. The dataset has 2 columns

```
user_id merchant_id
514729  14852,16695
1240327 23590
7457    211
359027  2483
463149  5802
514730  5460,1896
41953   7183,147105
927805  304,3909,4151,32,3,39171
```

As you can see that some user ids are associated with multiple merchants. What I am looking to do is transform the data in such a way that
I have the following schema

```
User Id MerchantId1 MerchantId2 MerchantId3 MerchantId 4
123445  0           1           0           1
123453  1           0           0           0
```

Basically I want to create a matrix of userid and merchant ids with a 1 or 0 based on if a user_id has a merchant_id or not.

Any suggestions/help on how I can accomplish this?

I am looking to use this to build a recommendation system. Any help would be great.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do from your sample data.

Comment: Specifically, you should show what specific result you would expect given a handful of your example rows. Otherwise we're all guessing as to exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is that you are after something like the following:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(mydf, "merchant_id", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
##   user_id merchant_id merchant_id_147105 merchant_id_14852 merchant_id_16695
## 1  514729 14852,16695                  0                 1                 1
## 2 1240327       23590                  0                 0                 0
## 3    7457         211                  0                 0                 0
## 4  359027        2483                  0                 0                 0
## 5  463149        5802                  0                 0                 0
## 6  514730   5460,1896                  0                 0                 0
## 7   41953 7183,147105                  1                 0                 0
##   merchant_id_1896 merchant_id_211 merchant_id_23590 merchant_id_2483
## 1                0               0                 0                0
## 2                0               0                 1                0
## 3                0               1                 0                0
## 4                0               0                 0                1
## 5                0               0                 0                0
## 6                1               0                 0                0
## 7                0               0                 0                0
##   merchant_id_5460 merchant_id_5802 merchant_id_7183
## 1                0                0                0
## 2                0                0                0
## 3                0                0                0
## 4                0                0                0
## 5                0                1                0
## 6                1                0                0
## 7                0                0                1
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to split it on a smaller sample of users. However on a total population where I have 1M users that have 36K merchants associated with them, the cSplit_e crashes R Studio. Any idea how I can run it on a bigger data sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1, mtabulate(strsplit(df1$merchant_id, ','))) 
#   user_id              merchant_id 147105 14852 16695 1896 211 23590 2483 3 304
#1  514729              14852,16695      0     1     1    0   0     0    0 0   0
#2 1240327                    23590      0     0     0    0   0     1    0 0   0
#3    7457                      211      0     0     0    0   1     0    0 0   0
#4  359027                     2483      0     0     0    0   0     0    1 0   0
#5  463149                     5802      0     0     0    0   0     0    0 0   0
#6  514730                5460,1896      0     0     0    1   0     0    0 0   0
#7   41953              7183,147105      1     0     0    0   0     0    0 0   0
#8  927805 304,3909,4151,32,3,39171      0     0     0    0   0     0    0 1   1
#  32 3909 39171 4151 5460 5802 7183
#1  0    0     0    0    0    0    0
#2  0    0     0    0    0    0    0
#3  0    0     0    0    0    0    0
#4  0    0     0    0    0    0    0
#5  0    0     0    0    0    1    0
#6  0    0     0    0    1    0    0
#7  0    0     0    0    0    0    1
#8  1    1     1    1    0    0    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user_id = c(514729L, 1240327L, 7457L, 359027L, 
463149L, 514730L, 41953L, 927805L), merchant_id = c("14852,16695", 
"23590", "211", "2483", "5802", "5460,1896", "7183,147105",
"304,3909,4151,32,3,39171"
)), .Names = c("user_id", "merchant_id"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```